# Creating even number of text with random function

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to create a set of blocks with random numbers on them but I want each number to appear at least twice.That is to say, every number has a pair.How can I achieve that?In this code I create a random number everytime I create a block.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function board(col, row) {

  if(col*row%2!=0){

     alert("You can't create a game.Give an even number of dimensions")
  }
  else {

     for (var i = 0; i < col; i++) {

     newDiv = document.createElement("div");
     divCol = "col"+i+" col-format";
     newDiv.className = divCol ;
     document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newDiv);

      for (var j = 0; j < row; j++) {

       newDiv = document.createElement("div");
       newDiv.className = "boxed";
       newHeadingTxt=document.createTextNode(Math.floor((Math.random()*col)+1)); 
       newDiv.appendChild(newHeadingTxt);
       newDiv.onclick = function() {clicked(this)};     
       document.getElementsByClassName(divCol)[0].appendChild(newDiv);
      }  

     }
  } 


 };


 </script>





 <style type="text/css"> 

 .col-format {
  float:left;
 }

  .boxed {
  width: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:1px;
  border:10px orange;
  background-color: orange;
  border-style:outset;
  }

 </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Create an array with the length of half the number of blocks.
2. Fill that array with random numbers
3. Duplicate that array
4. concat the two arrays and hussle the values
5. In your double for loop pick the value in this array at position (i * col) + j

   ```
   //+ Jonas Raoni Soares Silva
   //@ http://jsfromhell.com/array/shuffle [v1.0]        
   function shuffle(o){
     for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
     return o;
   };

   function createDoubles(col, row) { 
     var arr1 = [];

     // full arr1 with random values
     for (var x = 0 ; x < (col * row) / 2; x++) {
       arr1.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 10));
     }

     // copy arr1, concat and shuffle
     return shuffle(arr1.slice(0).concat(arr1));
   }

   function board(col, row) {

     if (col * row % 2 != 0){
       alert("You can't create a game.Give an even number of dimensions")

     } else {
       var randomValues = createDoubles(col, row);

       for (var i = 0; i < col; i++) {
         var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
         var divCol = "col" + i + " col-format";
         newDiv.className = divCol ;
         document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newDiv);

         for (var j = 0; j < row; j++) {
           newDiv = document.createElement("div");
           newDiv.className = "boxed";
           newHeadingTxt=document.createTextNode(randomValues[i*col + j]); 
           newDiv.appendChild(newHeadingTxt);
           newDiv.onclick = function() {clicked(this)};     
           document.getElementsByClassName(divCol)[0].appendChild(newDiv);
        }  
     }
   ```

   } 
    };

Comment: Can you explain number 5,please?

Comment: Look at the code. I added your board function as well and changed something. I did not test it out, but I think it's pretty close to what it should be. The `randomValues[i*col + j]` part is what I meant with step 5

Comment: When I give more columns than rows,some blocks appear as undefined,and beside that, some numbers are not pairs.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: When columns are 7 and rows 5,2 of the columns from the right are undefined,when col=9 and row=5, 4 columns from right are undefined.

Comment: I assumed that `col * row` would be an even number based on your own code: `if (col * row % 2 != 0) { alert("You can't create a game.Give an even number of dimensions")`. Both 7 * 5 (35) and 9 * 5 (45) are odd, so you should not pick these values. If it would not be even you could not always make pairs

Comment: Yes, you are right but I only used these numbers to state that the number of columns that is undefined is col-rows.The same thing happens when col=8/rows=6.

Comment: I think the error is in your code somewhere, because I do not see that issue when I test it. Please verify that first

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be too create an array of numbers and their pairs

```
[1,1,5,5,4,4,3,3,...]
```

Then shuffle it

```
[1,3,4,3,5,1,5,4,...]
```

and assign iterably to each div.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are making some sort of memory matching game?

I would generate a set of `(row * col / 2)` random numbers and add each one into an array twice and order the array randomly.

Then as you loop through generating the blocks, just pick and remove the first number from the array.